# Find Cities Within a Certain Distance From Address using MySQL

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems, geographic-distance

everyone:

I am completely stuck with this problem.  I have tried adding conditions as a WHERE statement, IF function in the SELECT statement, and ON statement when joining.  None of these produce the result I want.

WHAT I NEED:  A list of cities within 0.5 degrees latitude and 0.5 degrees longitude of a specific location.

WHAT I WAS GIVEN: Two tables - One table with a list of specific locations and another table with a list of cities as stated by US Census.

Table 1 includes:

```
Location Address
City
State
Location Latitude
Location Longitude
```

Sample Location Data:

```
Street              City        State  Latitude     Longitude
774 Emerson Street  Palo Alto   CA     37.44239044  -122.15956879
```

Table 2, which is US Census data, includes:

```
City
State
City Latitude
City Longitude
```

Sample City Data:

```
City            State Latitude     Longitude
Palo Alto       CA    37.44188309   -122.14302063
Mountain View   CA    37.38605118   -122.08385468
Sunnyvale       CA    37.36883      -122.0363496
```

So for example, if I have a location in Palo Alto, CA, I want something that looks like this:

```
Location        City          State
Palo Alto CA    Palo Alto     CA
Palo Alto CA    Mountain View CA
Palo Alto CA    Sunnvyale     CA
```

I tried:

```
SELECT d.`City`
      ,d.`State`
      ,l.`City`
      ,l.`StateAbbreviation`
FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised` AS d
     LEFT JOIN
     `LatLong` AS l
     ON d.`City` = l.`City` AND d.`State` = l.`StateAbbreviation`
WHERE l.`Latitude` BETWEEN (d.`Latitude` + 0.5) AND (d.`Latitude` - 0.5)
      AND
      l.`Longitude` BETWEEN (d.`Longitude` + 0.5) AND (d.`Longitude` - 0.5);
```

I tried:

```
SELECT d.`City`
      ,d.`State`
      ,l.`City`
      ,l.`StateAbbreviation`
FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised` AS d
     LEFT JOIN
     `LatLong` AS l
     ON l.`Latitude` BETWEEN (d.`Latitude` + 0.5) AND (d.`Latitude` - 0.5) &&     
        l.`Longitude` BETWEEN (d.`Longitude` + 0.5) AND (d.`Longitude` - 0.5)
```

I tried:

```
SELECT d.`City`
      ,d.`State`
      ,IF((l.`Latitude` < (d.`Latitude` + 0.5)) && (l.`Latitude` > (d.`Latitude` - 0.5)) &&  (l.`Longitude` < (d.`Longitude` + 0.5)) && (l.`Longitude` > (d.`Longitude` - 0.5)), l.`City`,NULL)
      ,l.`StateAbbreviation`
FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised` AS d
     LEFT JOIN
     `LatLong` AS l
     ON d.`City` = l.`City` AND d.`State` = l.`StateAbbreviation`
```

But these did not produce the results I wanted.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What was wrong with the results? Your query doesn't have any longitude limitations, which is probably important.

Comment: Oops. Forgot about that.  I have added that line which is the same as the latitude where statement.  The results show me an empty table.

Comment: Could you give us a couple of rows worth of data so we can get an idea for what the information stored in your database actually is?

Comment: I have added sample data in the question.

Comment: Please create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with your schema and this sample data.

Comment: That said, your query says `WHERE d.City = 'Seattle' AND d.State = 'WA'`, but your sample data says `Palo Alto, CA`. Either fix that or provide us with the actual data/query pairings.

Comment: Weird. I thought I fixed that.  Fixed now.

Comment: I'm starting to think I need to create a procedure or use a WHILE/IF statement.  Not sure this is right either.

Comment: I tried putting the latitude/longitude limits as conditions in an IF function, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE d.`City` = 'Seattle' AND d.`State` = 'WA'
AND
l.`Latitude` < (d.`Latitude` + 0.5) 
AND 
l.`Latitude > (d.`Latitude` - 0.5)
AND
l.`Longitude` < (d.`Longitude` + 0.5) 
AND 
`l.Longitude` > (d.`Longitude` - 0.5);
```

Or, this also works:

```
WHERE d.`City` = 'Seattle' AND d.`State` = 'WA'
AND
l.`Latitude` BETWEEN (d.`Latitude` + 0.5) AND (d.`Latitude` - 0.5)
AND
l.`Longitude` BETWEEN (d.`Longitude` + 0.5) AND (d.`Longitude` - 0.5);
```

Comment: see next answer

Comment: So I implemented the first solution because the second one didn't seem to work for me.  Even so, I only get one city per location instead of a list of cities per location.

Comment: Try and increase the distance and see if that returns more cities. Also, check your data, see if there are sufficient lat/long combinations for it to work with the distance you need. I have tested this with our geo table and it did return data.

Answer (score 0):

After much work, I was able to figure the primary part out using subqueries and a slight adjustment to my parameters:

```
SELECT `City`
      ,`StateAbbreviation`
      ,`Latitude`
      ,`Longitude`
FROM `LatLong`
WHERE `Latitude` BETWEEN (SELECT `Latitude` - 0.1
                          FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised`
                          WHERE `ID` = 1)
                      AND (SELECT `Latitude` + 0.1
                          FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised`
                          WHERE `ID` = 1)
      AND
      `Longitude` BETWEEN (SELECT `Longitude` - 0.1
                          FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised`
                          WHERE `ID` = 1)
                      AND (SELECT `Longitude` + 0.1
                          FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised`
                          WHERE `ID` = 1);
```

Now I have to figure out how to do this as a stored procedure for all 660 locations.  That would be a different thread if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
drop procedure if exists getNearLocations;
create procedure getNearLocations();
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
declare e INT default 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LocationDirectoryRevised INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
select ID from LocationDirectoryRevised into e;
  SELECT `City`
      ,`StateAbbreviation`
      ,`Latitude`
      ,`Longitude`
FROM `LatLong`
WHERE `Latitude` BETWEEN (SELECT `Latitude` - 0.1
                          FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised`
                          WHERE `ID` = e)
                      AND (SELECT `Latitude` + 0.1
                          FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised`
                          WHERE `ID` = e)
      AND
      `Longitude` BETWEEN (SELECT `Longitude` - 0.1
                          FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised`
                          WHERE `ID` = e)
                      AND (SELECT `Longitude` + 0.1
                          FROM `LocationDirectoryRevised`
                          WHERE `ID` = e);
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End
```

This will loop through the 660 locations and produce the data you are looking for.

This however, could be an expensive (slow) query because of the number of the subqueries but for 660 locations it should be sufficient.